# Showing hover text while moving Calendar Event from one place to another

Tags: gwt, hover, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

When user is moving one Calendar Event,  I want to show time where the user is going to place the calendar event as a tool tip of Calendar Event.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you're trying to do, but perhaps you could use DragStartEvent and DragEndEvent to display the make the tooltip element visible, like this (pseudocode):

```
onDragStart() {
  tooltip.setVisible(true);
}

onDragEnd() {
  tooltip.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Calendar event class is extending Record Class. So there is no method for setting hoverText. I also have to set text as because it's a dynamic Text (i.e., current position's time).
I want to fire the event which is automatically fired when user hovers Calendar Event.